# How to use volatility?

Tags: python, volatility

I am trying to use the `volatility` framework software to detect segmentation errors.

I am using the command:

```
python vol.py -f /Home/mycode/hex.c
```

I get the `error code not found.`

Please help.

Comment: A user's "home" folder is generally not capitalized. Is that a typo?